# Countdown clock works properly offline but doesnt work online

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a countdown clock on my front page that displays properly when I view the html file offline but on my server it doesnt work. On the server it displays the clock as random numbers scattered across the page. Here is my index.html. The clock is the div called `dw_clock`. In the hero section I've tried changing the positioning of the stylesheets in the header. I've also tried putting the css in the html code itself but i still have issues. I made a file with just two style sheets to see if Google Chrome 'inspect element' could even see the `Flipclock.css` but it doesnt seem to even see it, just the normal `style.css`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />


        <!--
        =================================
        STYLESHEETS
        =================================
        -->

        <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <!-- WEB FONTS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic" />

        <!-- ICON FONTS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple-line-icons.min.css" />



        <!-- OTHER STYLES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox/default.min.css" />

        <!-- MAIN STYLES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/FlipClock.css">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]> 



    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 



        <![endif]-->  


        <!-- COLORS -->
        <link id="color-css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/green.css" />
        <!-- <link id="color-css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/turquoise.css" /> -->
        <!-- <link id="color-css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/blue.css" /> -->
        <!-- <link id="color-css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/purple.css" /> -->
        <!-- <link id="color-css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/pink.css" /> -->
        <!-- <link id="color-css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/red.css" /> -->
        <!-- <link id="color-css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/orange.css" /> -->
        <!-- <link id="color-css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors/yellow.css" /> -->

        <!-- JQUERY -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body class="with-preloader">

        <!--
        =================================
        PRELOADER
        =================================
        -->
        <div id="preloader" class="preloader">
            <div class="preloader-inner">
                <span class="preloader-logo">
                    <img src="images/logos/preloader-logo.png" alt="EOS" />
                    <strong>Loading</strong>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="document" class="document">


            <!--
            =================================
            HERO SECTION
            =================================
            -->
            <section id="home" class="hero-section hero-layout-2 section parallax-background" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4">

                <!-- BACKGROUND OVERLAY -->
                <div class="black-background-overlay"></div>

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="hero-content">

                        <!-- HERO TEXT -->
                        <div class="hero-text">

                            <!-- LOGO -->
                            <div class="hero-logo wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s">
                                <img src="images/logos/hero-logo.png" alt="EOS - App Landing Page Template" />
                            </div>

                            <!-- TAGLINE -->
                            <h1 class="hero-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s">COMING SOON</h1>



                    <div class="dw_clock wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s"></div> 











                            <!-- WATCH THE VIDEO -->
                            <a href="#subscribe" class="hero-watch-video-link anchor-link wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Notify Me When Rhevon Is Released</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </section>





            <!--
            =================================
            FOOTER SECTION
            =================================
            -->
            <footer class="footer-section section" section id="contactus">



                    <!-- COPYRIGHT -->
                    <div class="copyright">Copyright &copy;   . All rights reserved</div>
                </div>
            </footer>

        </div>

        <!--
        =================================
        JAVASCRIPTS
        =================================
        -->
            <script src="js/Flipclock.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/retina.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.nav.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

can someone please help me, if it is needed i can upload the style.css file and the Flipclock.css file (that is the file that gives the clock all the needed styling) i have taken out most of the sites code as stackoverflow wont allow me to post because i have too much code, i also removed the header, as i dont think the issue is coming from there, and i've also not included the metadata, page title, or the favicon

Comment: i couldn't understand the bridge between the js and css.are you using any js?

Comment: yes, there is a js file i just dont understand why it all works when i view it offline but when i go online and view it off my website it isnt displayed properly. the js files one is script.js and one is called Flipclock.min.js as far as the js files go the clock does work properly, it just doesnt display properly online very similar to this http://flipclockjs.com/ mine looks just like that offline but online it is like this: www.rhevon.com

Comment: Might it be some sort of browser caching? Have tried ctrl + shift + F5?

Comment: i dont understand why im getting downvoted so much, this is my first post so i would appreciate if someone would tell me how i posted wrong. thanks

Comment: Nope - in fact console reports your flipclock.css is not loaded. Check your file is there and your paths are correct

Comment: Aaa - and bear in  mind that windows doesn't care about case sensitivity of file names, but on Linux server, the case matters - so check that

Comment: @rsobbi122:this might give you directions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a file casing.

Change your file name to http://www.rhevon.com/css/Flipclock.css

and this will work.

As I mentioned file names are case sensitive on Linux, that is why you had this working in local Windows environment. Your file name is 'Flipclock.css' not 'FlipClock.css'.

Don't forget to mark it as a valid answer, if it helped you.